# Referencing non-framework headers using framework syntax

Tags: objective-c

I have code that I build into a framework. It is sometimes useful, when debugging other project code relying on the framework, to instead build the source into the other project directly. The only issue is the way headers are referenced:

```
// Framework
#import <my_framework/my_widget.h>

// Source
#import "my_widget.h"
```

I could make a bunch of edits and go on my way, but I feel like there must be a clever solution to this, perhaps related to setting something for the Framework search path.

I'm curious about doing this in Xcode, though the raw command would also be useful.

**Update**

Despite some sensible advice, I'm having trouble getting this to work, so more explicit help would be great (and hopefully helpful to others).

```
// My framework source directory
/work/my_framework_project/source/widgets/my_widget.h
/work/my_framework_project/source/widgets/my_widget.m

// The framework that creates
/work/my_framework.framework/my_framework
/work/my_framework.framework/Headers/my_widget.h

// The project I'm debugging
/work/some_project/source/my_source.m
```

If I drop the framework into some_project, I refer to my header like this:

```
#import <my_framework/my_widget.h>
```

If I drop the reference to framework and add the source to the project, I need to do this, but don't want to:

```
#import "my_widget.h"
```

Note that I do not import `"my_framework/my_widget.h"` -- if that matters.

If I follow the first suggested answer, then I add this as a flag to the source files when I'm compiling them (currently by adding it in the "Compile Sources" area.

```
-I/work/my_framework.framework/Headers
```

This is not solving the issue of wanting to refer to the imports using the framework notation.

Comment: Solved it by making a subdirectory inside Headers called "my_framework" and copying all of the headers into this directory (and use the suggested "User header search path" solution). Note that a symbolic link in Headers (my_framework -> .) did not work, I needed a real directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> though the raw command would also be useful

Here it is:

```
<COMPILER> -Imy_framework_dir <other options...>
```

So you use the `-I` (uppercase 'i') flag for this (GCC or Clang style).

Xcode supports this feature using the 'user search header paths' section on the 'Build phases -> Compilation' tab of your project.

Comment: This will search my framework for the headers but use my source .m files, yes? I'm having trouble getting this to work. Your comment about 'Build phases -> Compilation" is "Compile Sources" on Xcode 4.5 yeah? I must have some pathing issues...

Comment: @BenFlynn 1. yes, 2. probably (I don't know the exact name/title, I don't use Xcode... Occasionally you may need to tick the 'Always search user header paths' checkbox on the same tab.)

Comment: Ok, it looks as though it adds the argument generally if you add it to  'Build Settings -> User Header Search Paths' or otherwise you can do it on a per-file basis with 'Build phases -> Compile sources'